# Pars values from lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, boto3

I have a list of multiple dictionaries (just one of many dictionaries in my list included below) that all have a single value I would like to extract, in the case it would be 'owner'

```
[
{'Key': 'owner', 'Value': 'connected@work.com'
},
{'Key': 'email_manager', 'Value': 'kort@work.com'
},
{'Key': 'boundary_id', 'Value': '344738728075'
},
}
]
```

Because owner is the actual value of 'Key' and the value of key 'Value' is the other piece of information needed im having a really hard time getting the desired output, something like:

owner: connected@work.com

I would like to only get that return for all my dictionaries in my list of dictionaries. For context the other dictionaries in my list follow the same formate as what is described.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempts? It would help us to help you if we could understand hat's wrong with your current output. For example: `for d in dict_list: if d['Key']='Owner':...`

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
keys = []
values = []

for elem in arr:
   keys.append(elem['Key'])
   values.append(elem['Value'])

new_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Comment: that did it thank you for the help! I was able to just add print(new_dict['owner']) and got the intended output.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```py
lst_dict = [
    {'Key': 'owner', 'Value': 'connected@work.com'},
    {'Key': 'email_manager', 'Value': 'kort@work.com'},
    {'Key': 'boundary_id', 'Value': '344738728075'}
    ]

new_lst_dict = [{value['Key'] : value['Value'] for value in lst_dict}]

print(new_lst_dict)

# Output : 
# [{'owner': 'connected@work.com','email_manager': 'kort@work.com', 'boundary_id': '344738728075'}]
```

Comment: I really like this solution, is there any way you can explain it to me, to better understand? I dont get how this works:

[{value['Key'] : value['Value'] for value in lst_dict}]

Comment: @Billy This technique I used is called dict comprehension and it means that for each value in lst_dict (for value in lst_dict) we will make a key:value pair (value['Key'] : value['Value']). Dict Comprehension ref : https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/